# How to inform CLion editor of -D<macro> arguments in a complex makefile project

Tags: c, clion

I have a complex (preexisting) makefile based project, which can be built in several ways. Depending on how, different -D compiler options might be set, but CLion has no way to know this implicitly. I have build/run configurations working fine for every build variation, but the code editor assumes none of the macros have been defined and thus does not provide help when editing some areas of the code.

For example, a C file might have

```
#ifdef AAAA
    //some configuration-specific code
#elif BBBB
    //some other configuration-specific code
#else
    //not 'greyed out' in CLion
#endif
```

Is there some option somewhere in CLion where I can tell the editor AAAA is defined, for example?

I have been through all the options I could find in CLion, but can't seem to figure out what mechanism CLion uses to analyze code in the editor. I would prefer if it were automatic based on the selected build/run configuration, but I would not mind adding a -DAAAA (or something like that) in some argument list somewhere in some options dialog and change as needed, or even if defining a custom compiler could help that would be fine too. There are so many options available for customizing I have to assume there is somewhere that controls how CLion's editor interacts with the compiler in the background.

Comment: not if you write makefiles yourself

Comment: Does it understand the Clang-style `compile_commands.json`? [It seems so.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/compilation-database.html)

Comment: Hmm, I like your thinking... I've used that on another project with some success, but CLion doesn't seem to want to consume the json while the makefile is in the project (it detects my project as a makefile project). I think I could get around this by putting the json elsewhere, and loading it as an independent project. I'm not sure how well that would work with the build/run/debug configurations, and it isn't ideal for changing configurations, but it is certainly worth a shot